# How to create a border around a hovered element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a border around an element, when it is hovered. Like this image:

[image]

The issue is that I don't want add to add border or outline on the element itself because I'm allowing user to change styles and it'll affect the added outline as well.

**Here is what I've tried to counter this:**

1. Created overlay `div` on top of the content using `position: absolute`
2. Added a `div` inside it to which is also set to `absolute`
3. Added `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` listener on overlay `div` to get the `width`, `height`, `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` of the element

Now the issue is that because the overlay is on top, the events are not firing on elements underneath (as I want the nested element's info as well). I've also tried setting `z-index` but it doesn't seem to be working as well.

So, how to achieve this?

PS: The screenshot is taken from the visual builder of Webflow but I'm not sure how they are achieving this.

**Here is the code:**

```js
var outlineContainer = document.querySelector('#content-container');
outlineContainer.onmouseover = outlineContainer.onmouseout = handler;

function handler(event) {
  var hoverOutline = document.querySelector('.hover-outline');
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
    console.log(event.target.tagName);
    var clientRects = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    hoverOutline.style.width = `${clientRects.width}px`;
    hoverOutline.style.height = `${clientRects.height}px`;
    hoverOutline.style.transform = `translate(${event.target.offsetLeft}px,${event.target.offsetTop}px)`;
  }
  if (event.type == 'mouseout') {
    hoverOutline.style.width = 0;
    hoverOutline.style.height = 0;
    hoverOutline.style.left = 0;
    hoverOutline.style.top = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
#content-container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hover-outline {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  z-index: 6;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.content {
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="hover-outline"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="component">
      <label>Hi</label>
    </div>
    <div class="component">
      <label>Text Field</label>
      <span class="wrapper">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Text Input Field" />
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe i'm not understanding the question, but did you try the css selector :hover?

Comment: As I'm allowing the user to change styles, the default functionality of CSS will not work in this case.

Comment: When you say the user can change styles, what can they do? For example, can they add a pseudo element, if not could you use that?

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood what is required, but could you just change the border color on hover? (And remove the JS).

```css
#content-container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
#content-container:hover {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hover-outline {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  z-index: 6;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.content {
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="hover-outline"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="component">
      <label>Hi</label>
    </div>
    <div class="component">
      <label>Text Field</label>
      <span class="wrapper">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Text Input Field" />
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```